# Remove files/folders from S3 that are x days old

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete files/folders from S3 bucket using Azure pipelines with task "AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell Script". Below is the powershell script that I am using:

```
Get-S3Object -BucketName "tfsonline-fullbuild-drop" | Where {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-S3Object -Force
```

This unfortunately is deleting every single file and folder from the bucket. It does not seem to be taking the `Where` command into consideration at all. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the last pipe and verify that your filter is working appropriately.  If not, troubleshoot before you delete.

Comment: Side-note: You can alternatively use [Amazon S3 Object Lifecycle Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on Amazon's site [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-S3Object.html) states that the `Get-S3object` cmdlet returns objects of type `Amazon.S3.Model.S3Object` or `Amazon.S3.Model.ListObjectsResponse`.  Neither of those object types have a `LastWriteTime` property.  In order to be sure you are testing the correct property, you need to determine exactly which properties the return object(s) has/have.  Reading the documentation will help, but another option is the `get-member` command.

If you were to take one of the returned objects and pipe it to `get-member` you can see all of the properties in the object being returned, and you can then make a good choice about how to do your test.  Something like this may help:

```
(Get-S3Object -BucketName "tfsonline-fullbuild-drop")[0] | gm
```

Good luck.